# How to produce events arriving as POST requests to a Confluent Kafka topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-producer-api, google-cloud-run

I'm working with an application that pushes event data as POST requests. I have no control over how the application sends the requests, and I have no control over how those requests look. I need to produce those events into a Kafka topic.

First I thought the Confluent REST Proxy API could work, but since I have no control over how the POST requests look, I can't use this API.

Then I thought that maybe there's a Confluent Connector, which would be nice because those can be scaled out and are nicely integrated with the Kafka cluster. But there's just a HTTP sink, just a source.

I'm on GCP and my research has taken me to Cloud Functions or Cloud Run. So now my idea is to write a small Python program (listen for requests, extract data from requests, and produce to the topic), make a Docker image and then deploy that on Cloud Run, which will hopefully scale it out.

I'm not very experienced, so my question is what is the best way to deal with this problem, maybe there is an obvious solution I'm missing.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are on the right path. You can use Cloud Function for data processing and then posting to the Confluent kafka topic. Another option would be to replace Congluent kafka topic with Google Cloud Pub Sub topic

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. I'm using KStreams for a streaming join and stateful aggregations later on, which doesn't work with Pub/Sub because it doesn't keep offsets. Is this something I could write a Confluent Connector for, I read you can write them yourself if you can't find one for your problem. Or would it be more work than using Cloud Functions?

Comment: I think it would be a more complex process to write a Confluent Connector, therefore I would recommend to use Google Cloud Functions